# Cypher query for gremlin traversal

Tags: cypher, gremlin

New to cypher query

```
g.V().has('Entity1','id',within(id1)).in('Entity2').
where(__.out('Entity3').where(__.out('Entity4').has('name',within(name))))
```

how to convert the above gremlin to cypher and return adjacent Entity2 invertex.

Here condition is
out('Entity3') should be out of Entity2
out('Entity4') should be out of Entity3 and name in the provided list of values

Return adjacent vertex of inEntity2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight answer:

```
MATCH (m:Entity1 )<-[:Entity2]-(n) 
WHERE (n)-[:Entity3]->()-[:Entity4]->({name: "ABC"}) 
       AND m.id in ["id1"]
RETURN n

# Assuming id is a property here. 

# If id is the actual ID of the node

MATCH (m:Entity1 )<-[:Entity2]-(n) 
WHERE (n)-[:Entity3]->()-[:Entity4]->({name: "ABC"}) 
       AND ID(m) in ["id1"]
RETURN n
```

I tried to create the graph for you use-case using this query:

```
CREATE (a:Entity2)-[:Entity2]->(b:Entity1 {id:"id1"}), 
    (a)-[:Entity3]->(:Entity3)-[:Entity4]->(:Entity4 {name:"ABC"})
```

the graph looks like this:

[image: sample graph]

However, I think while writing your gremlin traversal you had the intention of specifying the label of the vertex rather than label of the edge. That is why in the query I wrote to create the graph, the relationship and the vertex, relationship is pointing to have same label.

If that is your intention then your cypher query would look like.

```
MATCH (:Entity1 {id:"id1"})<--(n:Entity2) 
WHERE (n)-->(:Entity3)-->(:Entity4 {name: "ABC"})
RETURN n
```

Comment: MATCH (:Entity1 {id:"id1"}) id must be compared against list of values in gremlin so within used {id:"id1"} is not working .

Comment: I just updated the query to match ID using IN pattern instead of direct pattern matching. Have a look and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: missed in the first post  and updated   where(__.out('Entity4').has('name',within(name))) . How do we add in condition for out vertex of entity4

Comment: ```MATCH (m:Entity1 )<-[:Entity2]-(n)-[:Entity3]->()-[:Entity4]->(o) 
WHERE  m.id in ["id1"] AND o.name in ["ABC"] 
RETURN n  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are looking for as the Gremlin above seems incomplete compared to the description but I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
MATCH (e1:Entity1)<-[:Entity2]-(e2)-[:Entity3]->(e3)-[:Entity4]->(e4 {code: 'LHR'})
WHERE e1 IN (id1)
RETURN e2
```

Comment: want to return the vertex of connected edge of type Entity2 which must be out of Entity3 and Entity3 out of Entity4 
and Entity4.name within the list of values

Comment: below query has wrong syntax looking for something similar 

MATCH (entity1:Entity1)
WHERE entity1.id IN ['id']
AND (entity1)<-[:Entity2]-(in_Entity2)
AND (in_Entity2)-[:Entity3]->(out_Entity3)
AND (out_Entity3)-[:Entity4]->(out_Entity4)
MATCH out_Entity4 
WHERE out_Entity4.id IN ['name']
RETURN in_Entity2